# Issue with sending buffer over Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to send a Buffer to my browser over socket.io.  Supposedly this is supported as of 1.0.

Server code:

```
var tempBuffer = new Buffer(10);
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    tempBuffer[i] = i;
}
io.sockets.emit('updateDepth', { image: true, buffer: tempBuffer });
```

Client code:

```
socket.on('updateDepth', function(data) {
    console.log("update depth: " + data.buffer + ", " + data.buffer.length);
});
```

Everything looks good on the client side except that data.buffer is an ArrayBuffer (not a Buffer) and the length is undefined (the ArrayBuffer does not seem to contain anything).

Am I missing something obvious or is this not how it is supposed to work?  Many Thanks!

Comment: The operative question is whether `socket.io` is really equipped to handle sending and receiving of binary data?  The examples I've seen have always been strings or JSON (other stuff turned into a string), but I don't know what the capabilities of `socket.io` in this regard are.

Comment: You cant send a binary buffer over socket io. Take a look at [BinaryJS](http://binaryjs.com/)

Comment: You could base64 encode your buffer and send that string.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out this was working fine.  For some reason the Buffer didn't allow me to access it directly and it's length was undefined.  Converting it to a Uint8Array worked perfectly though.  I'm guessing that this is because even though socket.io will now send Buffer objects there is no guarantee that your client-side javascript will know what to do with them.

This does work:

```
socket.on('updateImg', function(data) {
    var imgArray = new Uint8Array(data.buffer);
    console.log("update img: " + data.buffer + ", " + data.buffer.length);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Buffer` is a node thing which browsers do not have native support for, but they do support Typed Arrays (better than a Buffer shim). So it makes sense to use a better container on the browser side.

Comment: And, exactly how to you propose to send a typed array if `socket.io` doesn't accept binary data?

Comment: Socket.IO 1.x supports binary data.

Comment: From the socket.io website: ["Socket.IO now supports emitting `Buffer` (from Node.JS), `Blob`, `ArrayBuffer` and even `File`, as part of any datastructure"](http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#binary-support).

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure this is supported in Socket.IO 1.0.  Just confounded that I don't seem to be able to receive it on the client side.