# How to send binary data with socket.io?

Tags: java, android, node.js, socket.io, binary

so I have been having real trouble sending binary data with socket.io  in node.js (Js client and Android client).

There is not much information neither in:

http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/

http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

I need to use socket io to send a binary array, that I create and fill.

the only code they give is the following:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost');
socket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
socket.send(new ArrayBuffer);
```

My answer is bellow.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Finally I have it working with JS and Android ( Java ), so I decided to share it with you guys.

Let's start with the Server Code: (Node js)

```
var http = require('http');

var app = http.createServer(function ejecute(request, response){});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);


io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('message', function(data){
            console.log("recieved data:");
            console.log(data);

            var bufArr = new ArrayBuffer(4);
            var bufView = new Uint8Array(bufArr);
            bufView[0]=6;
            bufView[1]=7;
            bufView[2]=8;
            bufView[3]=9;
            socket.emit('message',bufArr);
        });
    });
app.listen(3000);
```

Lets jump on to the Javascript client

```
  var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
  socket.emit('message', 'hola from js client');

  socket.on('message', function(msg){
    var bufView = new Uint8Array(msg);
    console.log(msg)
  });
```

And finally, let's show the Android (java) client:

```
    final Socket socket = IO.socket("http://localhost:3000",opts);

    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            socket.emit("message","hello from java");
        }
    });


    socket.on("message", new Emitter.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            byte[] bytearray = (byte[])args[0]; //received bytes

            for  (byte b : bytearray) {
                System.out.println("byte"+b);
            }
        }

    });

   socket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {}
});
```

I hope it is useful to you all.
Cheers!

Comment: this may helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498114/issue-with-sending-buffer-over-socket-io#comment41630083_26498165

Comment: Why do you want to send binary?

Comment: @ColinSmith i need it due to attempting to rewrite https://github.com/novnc/noVNC/blob/master/core/websock.js with socket.io