# How to send binary data from a Node.js socket.io (v2.0.x) server to a browser client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

- Engine.io send function do send binary data as binary, it can be seen
  in as binary in DevTools.
- Socket.io handles it as json ans sends it
  as text.

May be somehow Engine.io send function can be accessed via Socket.io instance?

May be I need to re-implement custom encoder/decoder for this?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question because may be it will save some time for someone.

Found out that binary data in format of Uint8Array cannot be sended properly, it is just needed to be converted to regular Buffer with new Buffer(...) and it will be transported by wire as binary

Answer (score 0):

This was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34056705/how-to-send-binary-data-with-socket-io/). The client code provided is written in java.

EDIT: there is also the javascript client code